# Can acoustics be a synonym for audio?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

With two recent questions:

[How quiet can a static, non-propulsive pulsejet be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/149662/how-quiet-can-a-static-non-propulsive-pulsejet-be)
[What frequency range would be ideal for audible communication on a planet with a thick atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/what-frequency-range-would-be-ideal-for-audible-communication-on-a-planet-with-a)

I found myself looking for a [acoustics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustics) tag with no luck.  Nothing comes up in the tags when I search for "hear" or "sound" either.  We have a [senses](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) tag, but that does not include the science of acoustics.

Finally, I found [audio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio).

> For questions asking about the creation of or propagation of sound.
>   Questions about how creatures or beings vocalize should use the
>   [vocalizations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocalizations) tag. Questions about music should use the
>   [music](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tag.
>
> For questions asking about the creation and propagation of sound
>   (compression waves) in any medium. Questions using this tag should be
>   asking about general world rules such as the nature of sound in a
>   specified atmosphere or the consequence of sound given a magical
>   event.
>
> Questions asking about how creatures or beings speak or vocalize
>   should not use this tag, but should instead us the vocalizations tag.
>
> Questions asking about music should not use this tag, but should use
>   the music tag instead.

To make it easier to find (only 4 questions before my retags), can we add [acoustics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustics) as a synonym?  I can't propose it because I don't have a score of 5+ for [audio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) (and synonym proposals are nearly invisible anyway).

Comment: Note: I retagged relevant questions with "acoustic" but there are tons with "frequency" and "sound" and so forth.  I actually enjoy the process of editing and retagging, but doing so would massively flood the home page.  This is a tag that, if easy to find, should be pretty popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

While I was there I reviewed three other pending synonym proposals.  I approved [aerodynamics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerodynamics) -> [flight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight) and left the other two pending meta discussion.  They are:

- [anthropology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthropology) (8 questions) -> [culture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) (504 questions): while the former encompasses the study of the latter, I don't know if that makes this a suitable synonym.  I haven't reviewed the questions.
- [medieval-europe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-europe) (89 questions) -> [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) (539 questions): I'm not a big fan of substring synonyms, especially *initial*-substring synonyms.  If [medieval-europe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-europe) didn't exist, anybody starting to type "medieval" would be directed to [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) -- problem solved!  Except that the tag got created and kept getting used, so something more complicated must be going on.  Further, I think we've had inconclusive meta discussions about whether "medieval" implicitly means Europe or if other cultures had medieval periods too.

If anyone wants to pursue either of these, please start a new meta question (ideally with some review of what's on those tags now).

Speaking of substring synonyms, while I was in there I also *deleted* [asteroid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroid) -> [asteroids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroids) and [planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) -> [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets).

And I also found [shoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoes) -> [footwear](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footwear), with *no* tagged questions, so I deleted that.

Comment: Thanks!  anthropology -> culture seems reasonable to me.  If we were a social science stack, they'd need to be separate, but, for our purposes, they're close enough.  We had a discussion on the whole set of era tags and they desperately need revamping.  I have been wanting to revisit that for a while, as we had great discussion but then nothing.  I suggest picking that up from the original.  https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/do-we-want-era-tags

Comment: @Cyn cultural or social anthropology <-> culture could be fine but the questions relating to [*biological* anthropology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65607/the-red-skin-gene) do not a good fit for **culture** synonymy (even in WB) make. Same with linguistics (not really culture though certainly highly related). So I think the meta would be warranted

Comment: @JGreenwell I'm open to hearing your arguments.  Why don't you start a new Meta question about it?

Comment: @Cyn if I get time to look more closely through the tags this weekend I will

Comment: @cyn I haven't forgotten this just got really, really busy will look this month when things calm down